# Proof of d'Alembert's ratio test for sequences tending to infinity

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Suppose that (**a**n) is a sequence such that (**a**n+1/**a**n) tends to l. Prove that if l is greater than 1 and an is greater than 0, for all n in the naturals, then (**a**n) tends to infinity.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If $l$ is greater that one, chose an $\varepsilon$ such that $l-\varepsilon > 1$ (give an explicit value for $\varepsilon$). By definition of what a limit is, there is an $N$ such that $a_{n+1}/a_n > l-\varepsilon$ for all $n>N$. Using this, you can easily show that $(a_n)_{n>N}$ is greater than a sequence that tends to infinity (which one?).